# Python - sorting incremented files

Tags: python, file, sorting, version

I have many folders that contains several versionned files. Here are example files:

> Cat_Setup_v01.mb
>
> Cat_Setup_v18.mb

The version number has a two characters padding. This way, I can easily sort files using:

```
 listFiles = glob.glob( myPath + "*.m*") # Retrieve files in my folder    
 listFiles.sort()
```

Unfortunately, I have some files with more than a hundred versions. Thus, my sorting method is broken with v1XX as they are sorted between v09 and v10.

Is there an efficient way I can sort my files in the right way without having to rename them all and change their padding?

`sorted(versionNumber, key=int)` combined with some split string operations could be an interesting trail but I'm affraid it will be too cumbersome.

I don't know Python much and as it seems to be an interesting language with a lot of possibilities, I'm pretty sure there is a more efficient way.

Cheers

Comment: I know it is not exactly what you are asking, but I would write a Python script that automatically changes all the filenames from *v01* into *v0001*.

Comment: My next task is to change the version padding as it is made using a Python script. 
However, I have arround 400 folders containing versionned files here, some of these files are currently used by other people. So, I'll just let them as they are and use @dragon2fly answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular Expression may help you.

```
import re

file=["Cat_Setup_v91.mb", "Cat_Setup_v01.mb", "Cat_Setup_v119.mb"]

print sorted(file, key=lambda x: int(re.findall("(?<=v)\d+", x)[0]))
```

give the output:

```
['Cat_Setup_v01.mb', 'Cat_Setup_v91.mb', 'Cat_Setup_v119.mb']
```

Updated: change `"(?<=v)\w*"` to `"(?<=v)\d+"` according to @Rawing comment

Comment: This will crash if there's a `v` character followed by a non-digit in the file name. If you're going to convert it to a number, _search_ for a number: `(?<=v)\d+`

Comment: If I understood and tested correctly `int(re.findall("(?<=v)\w*", x)[0]` returns the version number as an int. And `sorted()` uses this int as the key for sorting.


Edit: @dragon2fly @Rawing Works like a charm, cheers guys.
Python isn't an interesting language, it's an amazing one.

Comment: @DrHaze you are right. It first search for the number that followed the character v and then return a list of result. Since there is one result, so `[0]` will get the string of that number out of the list and then `int()` will convert it.